# Ng-bind is not working

Tags: angularjs

I have a issue in data binding using angularjs

I am  trying to bind the data from the controller view.
data has been successfully received in the response. i have assigned it in the datalist. while trying to loop the datalist using ng-repeat and ng-bind i cannot able to view. 
seems ng-repeat is working i can able to see the index looping successfully.
Kindly help on this issue.

Html

```
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in dataList">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td ng-bind="data.Name"></td>
            <td ng-bind="data.Email"></td>
            <td ng-bind="data.Phone"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Angular Js

```
      var myApp = angular.module('myModule', []);
      myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {
      $scope.dataList = [];
      $http.get('/Home/JsonValue').then(function (response) {
      if (response != null || response != "undefined") {
        $scope.dataList = response;
    }
})
  });
```

Json Data

```
   Data: Array(5)
      0:{Name: "Pramod", Email: "Pramod@gmail.com", Phone: "987654321"}
      1:{Name: "Prem", Email: "Prem@gmail.com", Phone: "123456789"}
      2:{Name: "Ram", Email: "Ram@gmail.com", Phone: "9811234343"}
      3:{Name: "Shyam", Email: "Shyam@gmail.com", Phone: "9889657454"}
      4:{Name: "Jitesh", Email: "Jitesh@gmail.com", Phone: "9535468899"}
```

Comment: how does your data look like

Comment: i have edited the data for your reference- @Sajeetharan

Comment: its not a valid json

Comment: sorry i have sent the data in .net format, now, i have edited correctly. @Sajeetharan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access the data property of response

```
 $http.get('/Home/JsonValue').then(function (response) {
      if (response != null || response != "undefined") {
        $scope.dataList = response.data;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, thanks you are correct just now i have tried.prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer just to correct your json format.
Though Sajeetharan's answer is correct but If your json is not in correct format, @Thiyagarajan your code won't display the json data even If you use `response.data`. Hence I have created an [**example**](https://jsfiddle.net/Y3BJa/517/) for your problem.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myModule', []);
myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.dataList = [
                {Name: "Pramod", Email: "Pramod@gmail.com", Phone: "987654321"},
                {Name: "Prem", Email: "Prem@gmail.com", Phone: "123456789"},
                {Name: "Ram", Email: "Ram@gmail.com", Phone: "9811234343"},
                {Name: "Shyam", Email: "Shyam@gmail.com", Phone: "9889657454"},
                {Name: "Jitesh", Email: "Jitesh@gmail.com", Phone: "9535468899"}
      ];
});
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: noted @MAC.  I have to the change the format from the backend

Comment: @Thiyagarajan I meant that only, this was just an example. You would need to change the format wherever the JSON is getting formed.

Answer (score 0):

Try by updating your JSON structure as follow,

```
[
  {"Name":"Pramod", "Email": "Pramod@gmail.com"}
]
```

(save it in json file and call that file using $http.get() method)